# filling a grid with from two different record (table) sources

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

I was wondering if there is any way to populate a table using two different records. My records have the same primary keys, but when I am adding the specific fields to my grid I have this error:

> More than one data (key) in one scroll.

I tried to make a Control view field in my primary record, and then refer the new record fields as relative fields but in this case the data is not populating in my grid. Any help or hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys finally after all discussion, and much try rounds I figured out how to do this.

You need to add a **draw a grid beside your old grid and populate it with a new record, which has dynamic view (dynamic sql)**. The only important case there, is you need to make sure **the order of your fields in your records, are in the same order of your fields in the `SELECT` statement of your sql**. Otherwise you will see

> an SQL error

.

Answer (score 1):

I've only done this where the 2nd record is a Derived/Work record.
Can you create a view that combines both records, and put the view in the grid?  FYI, peoplesoft let's you update the data in a view, which is not typical in an oracle db system.

Comment: I have tried to combine them in a view but had no luck

Comment: What about looking for an existing page where this is setup, in the way that you want.  Would the PeopleTools > Security > User Profiles > User Profiles component -> Roles page contain similar functionality to what you are trying to duplicate?

Comment: Also, is it possible that you have a problem with the order of keys?  Is there a level 0 record and is this a level 1 record?  Does the level 1 record have the same keys as the level 0 record?  Also, fyi, the order of fields matter, as well as the attributes of the fields in the records.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a field as display control field which is acting as primary key for its native table and as Foreign key for some other record.. A field needs to be made related if is being fetched from some other record... that is from the record which is not under current consideration. I think this way one can fetch data into grid or scroll respectively from multiple records.